# Auto rotate Google map in android

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps-v2

Does anyone know how I can auto-rotate the map using maps API v2 just like the google maps app does? Will I have to implement this functionality myself or is it in the API and i'm just not seeing it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can change the view using a lot of parameters, here you can see the documentation:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/views
an example for changing just the rotation can be:

```
CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()        
    .bearing(90)                // Sets the orientation of the camera to east
    .tilt(30)                   // Sets the tilt of the camera to 30 degrees
    .build();                   // Creates a CameraPosition from the builder
map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
```

Where bearing is the rotation clockwise regarding the north (not the actual bearing, it's absolute), while tilt is the inclination of the view, 0 is top of the map, 45 is halfly looking at the horizon.

Hope this helped.